# ERROR in src/app/users/users.component.ts(16,26): error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: angular

I have "Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'" issue 
when I use the subscribe method. Please have on the below code where am i 
missing the code.

"users.component.ts" file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-users',
        templateUrl: './users.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./users.component.scss']
    })

    export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
        users$ : Object;
        constructor(private data: DataService) { }
        ngOnInit() {
            this.data.getUsers().subscribe(
                data => this.users$ = data
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to provide the DataService class since the error is that getUsers() is void. My best guess is that you are defining getUsers in the DataService class as get getUsers(){return someStream;} in which case it is just a property and can be access by `this.data.getUsers.subscribe...` instead of `this.data.getUsers().subscribe...` however it is also possible you are just not returning the stream in getUsers() and all you need to do is return it in the DataService class.

Comment: Please format your question so it is readable and nice on eyes! I edited it a little bit.